# How to define many to many with Feathers and Sequelize with additional fields in join table?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am struggling to find the solution for that.

I want to have users which can belong to many organizations.
Each user can have a different role (I would prefer even roles but it sounds even more complicated...) at a specific organization.

In the table like `User_Organization_Role` I need to have fields like `role` (roleId?), `isActive`. Maybe some more.

I am using Feathers Plus generator but I do not think it matters in this case, however it may be beneficial to add something to the `schema` file?

I thought having belongsTo with simple `organizationId` field will be sufficient but I've realized that changing that to manyToMany, later on, would be painful so I think it is much better to implement that now.

I will appreciate any solutions / suggestions / best practices etc.

Answer (score 3):

`n:m` relations are by far the most difficult to handle, and there's really no one-size-fits-all solution. The biggest thing is to [read and understand this page and its sub-pages](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html), and then read them 2 more times for good measure. Try to focus on doing one thing at a time. I outline how I would approach this with feathersjs in this issue:

https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/852#issuecomment-406413342

The same technique could be applied in any application... the basic flow goes like this:

1. Create or update your primary objects first (users, organizations, roles, etc.). There are no relations made at this point. You need to have your objects created before you can make any relations.
2. Create or update the relations. This involves updating a "join" table (aka: "mapping" or "through" table) with data from step #1. The join table can (and should) have its own model. It should contain a foreign key for each of the objects you are associating (userId, organizationId, roleId etc.). You can put other fields in this table too.

Here is some pseudo code for how I would define my models (only showing relevant code for brevity). There is a little more to it than what I describe below, but this should get you started.

```js
const UserOrganizationRole = sequelize.define('User_Organization_Role', {
    // Define any custom fields you want
    foo: DataTypes.STRING
})

// Let sequelize add the foreign key fields for you.
// Also, save a reference to the relationship - we will use it later
User.Organization = User.belongsToMany(Organization, { through: UserOrganizationRole });
User.Role = User.belongsToMany(Role, { through: UserOrganizationRole });
Organization.User = Organization.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserOrganizationRole });
Role.User = Role.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserOrganizationRole });
```

... and here is how I would go about handling inserts

```js
const user = await User.create({ ... });
const org = await Organization.create({ ... });
const role = await Role.create({ ... });

await UserOrganizationRole.create({ 
  userId: user.id,
  organizationId: org.id,
  roleId: role.id,
  foo: 'bar'
});
```

... and finally, load the data like so:

```js
// Now we can reference those relationships we created earlier:
const user = await User.findById(123, {
  include: [User.Organization, User.Role]
});

const org = await Organization.findById(456, {
  include: [Organization.User]
});
```

Comment: I am working using feathers-sequelize so it is a bit different but I got to similar point, however I had to specify it more detailed e.g. 
users.belongsToMany(models.organizations, {
      as: 'organizations',
      through: {
        unique: false,
        model: models['users_organizations_roles']
      },
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
    users.belongsToMany(models.roles, { as: 'roles', through: {
        unique: false,
        model: models['users_organizations_roles']
      }, foreignKey: 'userId'})

Comment: The issue at the moment is that Sequelize does not create user-organization-role key when these three should be unique so no one will add user to the same org with the same role twice. Is  it achievable witrh Sequelize ?